# Pushing ViewController takes too long

Tags: swift, popup

I have a problem with my Swift application.
I am currently working on a QR-Code based entrance ticket systems for bigger events and I want to open up a view after I've successfully scanned the QR-Code.

The Problem is that after I scanned the QR Code the displaying of my content in my next view controller takes too long (30 sec or longer) to load.

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if metadataObjects.count != 0 && scanned == false
    {
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr
            {
                session?.stopRunning()
                data = object.stringValue!
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "result", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(function to get camera output and read the qr-code)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("LOADED")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

(added code in the popup view controller - rest is standard UIViewController code)

Every help is appreciated,
thank you!

Comment: Weird delays in UI can be the result of trying to initiate UI activities from a background thread. If that's not it, you're going to have to create a [minimal yet complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem and update your question with that code.

Comment: You need to post your code of how you get your data. If you are using an HTTP request to get data, your view controller is probably being pushed before the data returns.

Comment: Not that type of Data, I mean the text field with no extra code, just the text I inserted in the inspector.

Comment: You need to post your code.